# roslyn compiler gives undefined type error on type from another project

Tags: .net, roslyn

I have 2 projects in my solution. (I have many more, but for illustration purposes this is true...) 
In Project A there is a wrapper class around calls to a 3rd party library (SecureBlackbox - SBB - in this case).  In that class I use an SBB class called 'TElPGPReader'.  In Project A there are REFs to the necessary SBB assemblies.
In project B the wrapper class is used, but the SBB classes are not explicitly used.  However, in project B at the line that I use the (project A) wrapper class, I get the error:

```
error CS0012: The type 'TElPGPReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'SecureBlackbox.PGP, Version=16.0.329.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=903f968ced2ace33'.
```

Why would that be?  I know I can easily add the same refs to project B, but why should I need to?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these "old style" .NET projects or "SDK style" projects? I believe in the former, project references aren't transitive - but in the latter they are. If you can update to using an SDK style project, I suspect the problem will go away (and the project file will be much easier to maintain as well).

Comment: In terms of why it's needed - if there are overloads or method return types in project A which project B may not actively use, but which the compiler needs to understand, that would explain the problem IMO.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Not sure what you mean about old style vs. SDK style..
As far as return types, I checked and none of the constructors or methods used in B use any types/arguments besides strings and streams.

Comment: And none of the properties? Does it not mention any of the SBB types *anywhere* in the public API? For project types - have a look at your csproj file. If it starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` then it's an SDK style project (and is likely to be very small). If it starts with something like `<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` then it's an old-style project.

Comment: Thanks.  My projects are apparently "old style".
As far as properties, etc. and the public API... I am certain there exist public APIs that use SBB types/classes.  However, I would have thought that as long as I am NOT using any of those APIs, I shouldn't need the REF. Unless this is parallel to C/C++ where if I have an #include, and the .H file has some types that are not defined elsewhere (in a previous H file) I will get a syntax error...Is that the type of thing you thin is happening here? (I thought that "using" works differently...)

Comment: In order to check whether or not you're *actually* trying to use anything, the compiler needs to "understand" all the public members exposed in the API. I would treat this as a prompt to migrate your projects to SDK-style ones if you possibly can - they're much nicer in all kinds of ways; better dependency management is just one aspect of that.

Comment: Thanks Jon... I'll see if my management will agree to that...I expect not being in SDK style might be the cause of what I occasionally see - namely, a near full rebuild even after just changing code in what should be a low-level class, not dependent on anything else :-)